# Strikethrough in Section Title

Tags: sectioning, formatting, titles, strikeout

I am currently using `ulem` and `\sout` to do strikethroughs, but what if I want to strikethrough in a section title?

I'm using `hyperref` and receive the following error when I use `\section{\sout{..}}`:

```
Argument of \UL@word has an extra }.
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I don't appreciate the edits to this question. I don't see how removing my thanks was necessary or even appropriate.

Comment: And yet you did it again...

Comment: My apologies, but closing texts are not wanted on this site (or any stackexchange site) in general. Also some opening texts are even automatically removed by the system. I removed it as usual when I formatted your post. (I actually didn't saw your comment before my second edit.)

Comment: @Martin Can you link me to a meta post discussing the issue with this?

Comment: It's listed on the guidelines on the [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) page for once, but this post is relative new and also shouldn't be used for discussions. I'm looking for a better one at the moment, also on meta site http://meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Found it: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks' and taglines and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) and also [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed), it is also [in the FAQ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) (at least about signatures and tag-lines, but it also applies to other similar text). Keep in mind that this page is a Q&A Wiki, not a forum, so edits by other users are common and wanted in general.

Comment: While I concur about removing "thanks", I'd say the "Does anyone know how to do this?" is borderline. My main point, however, is this: In his first edit, @Martin accidentally re-inserted a typo that Caramdir had already removed, so right know, the question mistypedly says "strikethough" with a missing `r`. (I'm saying this because I can't do one-letter-edits.) Generally, I thought there's a system that should've told Martin or Caramdir – whoever started editing later – that someone's already editing this question?

Comment: @doncherry: "Does anyone know how to do this?" is on the border, but sounded very much a repetition of `but what if I want to strikethrough in a section title?`. I put it back in. There is a system which notifies users on already done edits, but they work asynchronous and do not fully work when two edits are saved shortly after each other (10 sec here).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As always you need to take extra care when using macros in moving arguments like section titles. They are written to the ToC and with `hyperref` also to the PDF bookmarks which only take text and no formatting.

Make sure to `\protect` all macros (`\sout` is already protected). The solution in [Why hyperref doesn't like commands set via \let in section titles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22215/why-hyperref-doesnt-like-commands-set-via-let-in-section-titles/22217#22217) didn't worked, but using `\texorpdfstring` does. I recommend to use an own wrapper macro which uses `\texorpdfstring` internally and is defined using `\DeclareRobustCommand` (or `\protected\def`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\hsout}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\sout{#1}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{\hsout{Striked out section title}}\label{foo}

\ref{foo}

\autoref{foo}

\nameref{foo}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by putting `\sout` inside of `\section`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}

\section{\sout{Striked out part} of a section title}

\end{document}
```

[image: Striked out part of a section title]

### Making it work with hyperref

To make this work with `hyperref` either use `\texorpdfstring` as in

```
\section{\texorpdfstring{\sout{Striked out part}}{Striked out part} of a section title}
```

or use the optional argument of `\section` as in

```
\section[Striked out part of a section title]{\sout{Striked out part} of a section title}
```

Comment: I tried this...

Comment: @BBischof It compiles alright on my system (TeX Live 2009) and looks alright. What is the problem?

Comment: @BBischof: Are you using any package which processes section titles, like `nameref`? What error message are you getting?

Comment: Doesn't work with `hyperref`, at least not out-of-the-box

Comment: I am using hyperref.

Comment: idk if this is still necessary, but "Argument of \UL@word has an extra }."

Comment: @BBischof,@N.N.: related to this issue: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22215/why-hyperref-doesnt-like-commands-set-via-let-in-section-titles. Try using the optional argument of `\section` without `\sout`.

Comment: The usual `\texorpdfstring{\sout{...}}{...}` seems also to work.

Comment: My suggestion: `\DeclareRobustCommand{\hsout}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\sout{#1}}{#1}}`
 and use `\hsout` instead.

Comment: Please make that an answer Martin.

Comment: @BBischof: I undeleted my answer now. Please add `@Martin` to your comment next time so that I get notified. Otherwise it's hard to notice it.